# pandas how to get all rows with specific count of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe

```
df = 

    C1 C2
    a.  2
    d.  8  
    d.  5  
    d.  5  
    b.  3
    b.  4
    c.  5
    a.  6
    b.  7
```

I want to take all the rows, in which the count of the value in C1 is <= 2, and add a new col that is low, and keep the original value otherwise. So the new df will look like that:

```
df_new = 
C1 C2 type
a.  2  low
d.  8  d
d.  5  d
d.  5  d
b.  3. b
b.  4  b
c.  5. low
a.  6. low
b.  7  b
```

How can I do this?

I also want to get back a list of all the types that were low (['a','c'] here)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and count the value of `'C1'` in each group. Then use `lambda` in [`pandas.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and return `low` or the original value of the group. Or we can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) on the result of `groupby`.

```
df['type'] = df.groupby('C1')['C1'].transform(lambda g: 'low' if len(g)<=2 else g.iloc[0][:-1])

# Or we can use 'numpy.where' on the result of groupby
g = df.groupby('C1')['C1'].transform('size')
df['type'] = np.where(g<=2, 'low', df['C1'].str[:-1])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   C1  C2 type
0  a.   2  low
1  d.   8    d
2  d.   5    d
3  d.   5    d
4  b.   3    b
5  b.   4    b
6  c.   5  low
7  a.   6  low
8  b.   7    b
```

Comment: Please see edit - how can I get the specific types that are above 2 (in this case ['a','c'])

Comment: @Cranjis, try this: `df.loc[df['type'] == 'low', 'C1'].str[:-1].unique().tolist()`